# Does referencing a member prevent GC on parent object?

Tags: javascript, garbage-collection

Say I have something like:

```
function getMember() {

    var myRoot = {
       a: {val: 1},
       b: {val: 2}
    };

    return myRoot.a;
}

var myMember = getMember();
```

How does javascript treat the `myRoot` object after it goes out of scope? Will it (and its "remaining" member `myRoot.b`) be garbage collected even if a live reference to `myRoot.a` exists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does referencing a member prevent GC on parent object?

No.

Unless that member has a circular reference back to the parent object, or contains/is a function that closes over it, of course, but that's not the case here.

> How does V8 treat the myRoot object after it goes out of scope?

It will be treated like every other object. The `myRoot` variable will go out of scope, and the object will no longer be referenced by anything, so it is eligible for garbage collection.

It might even have been stored on the stack, which means that its memory is immediately re-claimed when the function returns.

> Will it (and its "remaining" member myRoot.b) be garbage collected even if a live reference to myRoot.a exists?

Yes. The reference is not to "`myRoot.a`", but to the object `{val: 1}` on the heap. It doesn't have a name attached.